# Fast.ai:ModuleAttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'fine_tune'

Tags: python, pytorch, image-classification

When I use the fast.ai, T encounter this problem,the follow is my code:

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
from fastai.text.all import *
from fastai.collab import *
from fastai.tabular.all import *

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

path = untar_data(URLs.PETS)/'images'

def is_cat(x): return x[0].isupper()

dls = ImageDataLoaders.from_name_func(
    path, get_image_files(path), valid_pct=0.2, seed=42,
    label_func=is_cat, item_tfms=Resize(224))

learn = cnn_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=error_rate).to(device)

learn.fine_tune(1)
```

It shows :"ModuleAttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'fine_tune'"

Comment: Similar problem with learn.fit_one_cycle but the error is "no attribute 'fit_one_cyle'"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fast.ai not using the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351366/fast-ai-not-using-the-gpu)

Answer (score 0):

fastai will select GPU for you if available.

I reproduced your problem and getting rid of the `.to(device)` call in the Learner got the error away:

```
learn = cnn_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=error_rate)
learn.fine_tune(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error and resolved it by adding the line `from fastai.schedule.callback import fine_tune` at the top of the file.

Here's the code for the `fine_tune` method in the fastai library: https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/b273fbb32d075ef1d6fd372687b5f56564cead9a/fastai/callback/schedule.py#L161

```
# %% ../../nbs/14_callback.schedule.ipynb 60
@patch
@delegates(Learner.fit_one_cycle)
def fine_tune(self:Learner, epochs, base_lr=2e-3, freeze_epochs=1, lr_mult=100,
              pct_start=0.3, div=5.0, **kwargs):
    "Fine tune with `Learner.freeze` for `freeze_epochs`, then with `Learner.unfreeze` for `epochs`, using discriminative LR."
    self.freeze()
    self.fit_one_cycle(freeze_epochs, slice(base_lr), pct_start=0.99, **kwargs)
    base_lr /= 2
    self.unfreeze()
    self.fit_one_cycle(epochs, slice(base_lr/lr_mult, base_lr), pct_start=pct_start, div=div, **kwargs)
```

Notice I call it a "method", but it's not defined on a class. Wonder what's up with that?

You see that `@patch` decorator?

Check out the definition of the `patch` function in the fastcore library: https://github.com/fastai/fastcore/blob/master/nbs/01_basics.ipynb

And that led me to what I expected was the solution. You just need to import the module that patches the class with the method.